# Prevent issues with stale elements due to ajax loads

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I have a page that I'm trying to drive with selenium (in python, but I understand that this could apply to other languages that have implemented Selenium).

The page contains a paginated table and a filter row.

The action I am trying to perform is to locate a row in the table and click on a link in that row. To avoid issues with pagination (my row may not be visible in the table), I populate the filter, action the filter, and then will have a reasonable expectation that my row will be there. If it's not, then I should get an exception, which is acceptable.

My issues are two fold.

The first is that I may have navigated to this page from anywhere, including the same page. So when I attempt to find the filter element, it may do so before the navigation is complete, so the located filter element ends up being stale.  I've considered doing a limited retry loop, catering for the stale element exception, but from what I can see, this is not recommended, though I can't find a viable alternative.

The second is that once the filter is actioned, I go looking for my row using a `wait.until`. However, the row may have already been on the first page of the paginated table, so it finds it immediately, but then filter does it's ajax magic and the element becomes stale. Is there a way to detect a content change, so my `wait.until` doesn't kick in until it's had a change to execute.  Currently, I've put a `thread.sleep(1)` after the filter is actioned, to give the ajax a chance to run, but I've read that's not great either.

My filter code is as follows, and shows usage of it via `is_call_route_setup`.

My `BasePage` class gives me some basics such as access to the web driver on `self.driver` and a preconfigured `WebDriverWait` available on `self.wait`.

There's a slight chance that the application may not use Ajax to apply the filter at all, and may just use a plain POST to get the results.

Are there ways to halt operations until a page has done it's Ajax or POST operation?

```
class CallRoutingPage(BasePage):
    def filter(self, filters):
        """Use the filter, but be sure to clear the filters first"""
        default_filters = {
            'filter_rule': None,
            'filter_name': None,
        }

        new_filters = default_filters.copy()
        new_filters.update(filters)
        element = None
        for name, value in new_filters.items():
            element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, name)),
                                      message='Unable to locate filter input with name {}'.format(name))
            element.clear()
            if value is not None:
                element.send_keys(value)

        element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  # can't use .submit, due to invalid form element in table markup

        sleep(1)  # wait for ajax to kick in so we don't locate stale elements

    def is_call_route_setup(self, source: str, destination: str, clazz: str, host: str, status: str,
                            first_connection: str, route_name: str) -> Tuple[bool, Union[str, None]]:
        """Generic function to test if a call route has been set up"""

        logger.debug('Verifying call route setup for route_name {}'.format(route_name))

        # find a route by route name
        self.filter({'filter_name': route_name})

        try:
            sleep(1)  # manual sleep to prevent picking up the table cell before the refresh has executed
            route_name_element = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//td[@class='tblcell'][text() = '{}']".format(route_name))
            ))
        except TimeoutException:
            return False, 'ROUTE_NAME_NOT_FOUND'

        # more stuff happens after
```

Comment: I've found http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html, which shows what could be a best practice method of waiting until a page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that come to mind are requestIdleCallback:

```
driver.execute_async_script("""
  window.requestIdleCallback( () => arguments[0]() )
""")
```

But that might fire early if the ajax takes a while. Also MutationObserver:

```
m = driver.execute_async_script("""
  new MutationObserver( m => arguments[0](m) ).observe(document.body, { childList: true } )
""")
```

That one could work well if you know what part of the dom will change.